# Search and replace consecutive capital letters in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to find all the acronyms in a Word document. I thought of using special characters in the search field. So I am looking for [A-Z] but this gives every capital, and [A-Z][A-Z] gives only two. I could do that for every length (and every one of my documents) but I feel like there is a faster solution.

How could I select words composed only of capitals in the search bar?
How can I also include plurals (+ s lower case at the end of words)?
How can I reuse the words I found with special characters in the replace bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for words containing only capital letters with `<[A-Z]@>`

To search plural forms use `<[A-Z]@s>`

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do it in the same expression.

To what special character you want to replace? You can find several useful tips on the internet, e.g. on [Office site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)

Based on your comment: you can refer to the text you found by `^&`, so to add `(acr)` after each found item, just put `^&(acr)` in the replace to field.

Comment: Let say I want to replace acornyms by acronyms + '(acr)', I look for <[A-Z]@>, can I use something like <[A-Z]@> + '(acr)' in the replace bar (or some sort of ANS + '(acr)')